# Unexpected behavior with `map` and `apply` / `call`

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I was just experimenting around with the `Function.prototype.call` and `Function.prototype.apply` function, when I stumbled upon an error that I didn't understand:

I wanted to trim all the elements in an array, Naturally, I would have written:

```js
const arr = [' text 1   ', '\n\ntext 2 '];
arr.map(str => str.trim());
```

Which works just fine.

But, for some reason, all the following options give me an error :

```js
arr.map(String.prototype.trim.call);
arr.map(''.trim.call);
// => Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

arr.map(String.prototype.trim.apply);
arr.map(''.trim.apply);
// Uncaught:
// TypeError: Function.prototype.apply was called on undefined, which is a undefined and not a function
//     at Array.map (<anonymous>)
```

But, when I call them outside of the map, or in the map but in a function, like that:

```js
arr.map(str => ''.trim.call(str))
```

It runs without issue... Why is that?

Comment: What's the eror ?

Comment: The `call` method takes a scope as the first param, here you are passing the current item to it.

Comment: I updated the question with the error messages

Comment: You need to look at the documentation for the call function : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: `arr.map(String.prototype.trim.call, String.prototype.trim);` works, I think the error you see is related to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Called_on_incompatible_type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is that?

There is a difference between calling a function as a method of an object or standalone. If you call it as a method the `this` will value inside the function will be set automatically to the object. If you call it "standalone" `this` will be `undefined` (in strict mode).

It might not look like it, but in

```
String.prototoype.trim.call('foo')
```

you are calling the `.call` *method* of the `trim` function. The `this` value inside `call` will refer to `String.prototype.trim`, i.e. the function you want to call.

In

```
const call = String.prototype.trim.call
call('foo')
```

(which is what happens in your `arr.map` example), `this` inside call `call` will be `undefined`. `call` doesn't know which function should be executed.

Simplified example:

```js
'use strict'

const obj = {
   call() {
     console.log('this', this)
   }
}

obj.call()
const call = obj.call
call()
```

---

There are multiple ways to solve this (as you discovered yourself). Another way is to *bind* the `this` value of the function to a specific value (which returns a new function). It's a bit unwieldy though:

```
// Might as well refer to Function.prototype.call directly
arr.map(Function.prototype.call.bind(String.prototype.trim));
```

Of course you can create a helper function for that:

```js
function callable(func) {
  return func.call.bind(func)
}

const arr = [' text 1   ', '\n\ntext 2 ']
console.log(arr.map(callable(String.prototype.trim)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to apply the `String.prototype.trim` to an array. You will want to map the array items. This is not the same as `Math.max(...numberArray)`, because trim is neither static, nor does it take an array of arguments.

You have two options:

1. An inline lambda within the `Array.prototype.map` call:

```js
const data = ['foo   ', '   bar', '   baz   '];
const trimmed = data.map(s => s.trim());

console.log(trimmed);
```

2. A callback reference `Array.prototype.map` call:

```js
const trimFn = (s) => s?.trim();

const data = ['foo   ', '   bar', '   baz   '];
const trimmed = data.map(trimFn);

console.log(trimmed);
```

If you really want this behavior, you could add a static method to the `String` class/object.

```js
// Add a static trim method to the String class.
Object.defineProperty(String, 'Trim', {
  value(str) {
    // OR return String.prototype.trim.call(str ?? '');
    // OR return String.prototype.trim.apply(str ?? '');
    return String.prototype.trim.bind(str ?? '')();
  },
  writable: false,
});

const data = ['foo   ', '   bar', '   baz   ', null];
const trimmed = data.map(String.Trim); // Use the static method as a callback

console.log(trimmed);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I didn't try to apply the trim function to the array, I applied it to each element of the array, via the `map` method.